# how to combine values from Datepicker & Timepicker in one variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, datepicker, angularjs-ui-utils

I have angular App U I have Datepicker & Timepicker using angular-ui  when user select date `$Scope.dt` and set time `$Scope.mytime` I am trying to combine in one $Scope.SelectedDateTime I get NaN. I don't know how to fix it

update 
when user select date $scope.dt value will be 'ok when user select date it will 'Thu Mar 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)' and $scope.mytime value 'Thu Mar 05 2015 23:30:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)' how to combine them in one variable 
html

```
      <h4>Popup</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="SelectedDateTime()">Today</button>
```

javascript

```
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();
    $Scope.mytime = new Date();
 $scope.changed = function () {
    $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
  };

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.mytime = null;
  };
    $Scope.SelectedDateTime = function()
    {
      var SelectedDateTime = $scope.dt +''+$scope.mytime;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share changed() code. As per your code, you are trying to add two dates and it will fine

Comment: if possible setup a jsfiddle. Something which could be the reason for NaN is one of the operator is undefined and others are number

Comment: I tried using plunker and jsfiddle they aren't working

Comment: Cool, share those urls. I will try

Comment: I mean it is not render the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate or try to add date objects as if they are numbers.

What you are basically trying to do is

```
new Date() +" "+ new Date()
```

Paste that line into browser console and you will see something like:

```
"Thu Mar 05 2015 21:54:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) Thu Mar 05 2015 21:54:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```

You need to deal with them as Date objects and use appropriate Date prototype methods to manipulate them

Some of the methods you would need would be:

```
Date.prototype.getHours()
Date.prototype.setHours()
```

Above assumes that you are trying to actually create a new DateTime. If not it is not clear what your expected results are

Reference: [MDN Date.prototype Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype)

Comment: what I trying to do is to take the combine  two variable date and time in one variable

Comment: I realize that, but what is it supposed to be? I assumed you want the time to adjust on the date no? `one variable` could be type string, date object, timestamp etc.

Comment: yes because when user select date from datepicker  the time part will be '00:00:00 ' and user will set the time on timepicker just want to get thepart is set by user and combine in one variable

Comment: OK, so I've given you the information needed correctly then. Also you won't have any problem finding lots of tutorials on manipulating dates

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem using the same ng-model for Datepicker and Timepicker.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myDateModel" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ... />

<uib-timepicker ng-model="myDateModel"...></uib-timepicker>
```

I hope it helps you too! Good luck!

Comment: Perfect in it's simplicity :)